# How to perform Load testing of SignalR projects

Tags: c#, signalr, load-testing

I have created a project using SignalR C#.
I wanted to perform the load testing. Suggest some ways to perform the same.

Comment: You perform Load testing by performing load testing.

Comment: Load testing is irrelevant of technology you use. What do your endpoints do? What data do they serve? Your load testing should focus on revealing how your system performs with normal load (number of requests) and with max capacity load. For example if you have an endpoint intended to be used by 1000 users during normal day but on some specific occasion (such as holiday) you expect three times the load, your load testing should construct those scenarios, run requests against your target, that should tell you strengths/weaknesses of your complete system.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar Thank you. 
I am creating a chat software. Where I am targeting 5000 users at a time. I wanted to create scenarios, but don't know to how. 

can you help me with the same.

Comment: Sure! I think you will have to gather other parameters such as average message size, types of messages (audio/video/image/text), size limitations in play (e.g. whatsapp puts 25mb limitation), frequency of messages your users are likely to use. List all these out, put numbers against them, and that should drive your load testing effort. Are you using any automation to drive load tests?

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar Thanks for help. I understand what I have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load Testing assumes putting the system under the anticipated load so you need to

1. Mimic real life system usage with 1 thread (virtual user)
2. Add more threads and see how does the system behave in terms of throughput, response time, number of errors, etc.

If you're looking for the load testing tools you can consider:

1. [Crank, the tool for SignalR performance testing from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-connection-density-testing-with-crank)
2. [signalr-tester](https://github.com/emtecinc/signalr-tester)
3. Or any other tool which supports [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) and [Async Requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-async-requests-with-jmeter)